# Can KWallet manage my ssh passwords?

Tags: ssh, security, kde, password

I need a way to store some SSH passwords. Note that these are **login passwords** which I need to pass to ssh; key authentication is unfortunately not an option. I'd like to be able to have KWallet fill them in for me somehow, because I think Gnome-keyring can do this. Does anyone know if KDE has this functionality in KWallet? And if so, how I can set it up to make use of it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have KDE handy but I poked at `gnome-keyring` a little bit and it looks like it accomplishes this by providing the ssh client with an alternate `askpass` program.

Check the value of `$KWALLET_ASKPASS` from your terminal in KDE. If it is set to something try this: `export SSH_ASKPASS=$KWALLET_ASKPASS`.

If not look around through your distro's packages and see if there is an `askpass` replacement program associated with `kwallet`. If so, set `SSH_ASKPASS` to that program.

Comment: Does that work even for a password (as opposed to a key passphrase)? OpenSSH is very finicky about reading passwords only from a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [KDE feature request](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81067) from 2004 to use kwallet as an ssh agent. You might want to comment or vote on that bug.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be possible now using ksshaskpass (https://archlinux.org/packages/?name=ksshaskpass) using something similar to what Caleb suggested.

guide here https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/KDE_Wallet#Using_the_KDE_Wallet_to_store_ssh_key_passphrases

Comment: Unfortunately this refers to SSH Key passphrases, not basic login passwords.

Comment: I see, i'm sorry i misunderstood.
Maybe a script could be created, to poll the credentials from kwallet and pipe to the process needing it.